# Auto sum amount based on categorized expense

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a financial spreadsheet with 2 data areas, 2 columns each area.

- Area 1: Expense Amount, Expense Category (data validation list)
- Area 2: Expense Category (as a list in 5 rows) , Total Expense Amount.

I would like to select an Expense Category to an Expense Amount and have that amount adding to a running total in the appropriate list row in Area 2.  So if $100 is categorized as Groceries it would then append that amount to the Groceries list row in Area 2's Total Expense Amount.

For example:

- Area 1: $100, Groceries (data validation list category) 
  would change Area 2 Grocery list row...
- Area 2: Groceries, $150 (which includes a previous expense amount of $50 [=50+100])

If the category is Auto Gas then it would append Area 2's Auto Gas row Total Expense.

Is this possible with just formulas and/or conditional formatting? Is VBA required?

Comment: Sounds like a pivot table would work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SUMIF formula for this.

Let's assume that Area 1 is in columns A and B, and Area 2 is in columns E and F.

In Area 2, assuming the Total Expense column is to the right of the category name, insert this formula in the Total Expense field for each category: `=SUMIF(B:B,E#,A:A)` (the # in the middle is the row number, so E2 for Groceries, E3 for Auto Gas, etc.)

My data:

Area 1:

[image: Area 1]

Area 2:

[image]

**How it works in a nutshell:**
The SUMIF statement asks for a range you want to look for a particular value in (B:B in this case, for the Category), the criteria you want to look for in that range (E#, the category name in our Area 2), and then looks for any values in the sum range that are across from the the matches in your first range.